# Possible causes of garbage collection thread constantly using 100% cpu

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In our production tomcat deployment (Tomcat 8 + JVM 8) we have recently started observing that occasionally the garbage collection threads start using 100% cpu. 
It is not a spike in usage. When it happens, the behavior persists and the only remedy is a system restart.

We took a heap dump during this time but unfortunately the dump file does not open using any tool - jhat or jvisualvm. Hence, we are unable to pin point the code where the allocation took place.

Why does this scenario happen ? Is it because the application has created a lot of objects and processing is taking a long time ?

(Note: We do have memory intensive functionality; hence an OutofMemoryError would have made sense than 100% cpu usage)

Comment: This is a classic memory leak. The fact that it's a web application makes it even more likely. Time to dust off the profiler...

Comment: Open the heap dump by using eclipse MAT, it will pinpoint the culprit class.